# What is the difference between std::uninitialized_default_construct() and std::uninitialized_value_construct()?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, placement-new

There are two almost identical algorithms in STL:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_value_construct

The only difference is:

```
for (; current != last; ++current) {
    ::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*current))) Value();
}
```

vs.

```
for (; current != last; ++current) {
    ::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*current))) Value;
}
```

Could you explain the difference?

And for what reason they exist along?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization versus https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: `*new int()` is zero whereas `*new int` is UB as reading uninitialized variable

Comment: @Jarod42 for complex types there is absolutely any difference, right?

Comment: I don't think the suggested question answers when the above 2 functions would be used

Comment: Found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402